# What is the song in episode 3 of Your lie in April

Tags: music, your-lie-in-april

what was the music playing at background at 12:10 in episode 3 of *Your lie in April*

[image]

Comment: To clarify, are you referring to the music that plays in the screenshot you uploaded, or to the classical piece that is played at the high school? The screenshot is from a couple seconds before 12:10, and it's the the classical piece that comes in at 12:10. If it's the classical piece, it is probably Saint-Saën's _Rondo capriccioso_, but I'd have to listen to it to confirm for sure.

Comment: Should be. There even is [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hCsB3WtlyaM) version with Kousei as background image.

Answer (score 1):

Confirmed at 12:10 the classical piece is "Saint-Saëns: Introduction & Rondo Capriccioso in A Minor, Op. 28" by Alexandre Da Costa

The song played earlier in the mentioned photo above is "Bansou Bansou" by Anime de Japan